# Problema con setText() en java

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola estoy tratando de cambiar el texto de un JTextArea desde otra clase, para ello cree un metodo que se encargue de ello, el problema es que cuando creo el objeto de la clase donde se encuentra el campo de tipo JTextArea e intento cambiar el texto con setText() no se visualiza para nada, pero si lo imprimo en consola si aparece el texto que puse con el metodo, aqui el codigo

Declaración del objeto:

```
private JTextArea area1;
```

Inicialización:

```
area1 = new JTextArea();
```

Dándole tamaño:

```
area1.setBounds(20, 200, 500, 160);
```

Agregarlo a la lámina:

```
add(area1);
```

Aquí el método con el que trato de cambiar el texto:

```
public void setRegistro(String registro) {

    area1.setText(registro);

}
```

Creando el objeto desde la otra clase:

```
        laminaVista vista1 = new laminaVista();

try{

  //codigo no relevante

}catch(IOException e){

  vista1.setRegistro("Mensaje de error");

}
```

Comment: Pero ¿a qué contenedor le estás agregando el `JTextArea`?

Comment: ¿ Podrías ponernos el codigo entero relevante  de las 2 clases que estas usando ? no solo porciones para poder verlo con mejor claridad y probarlo de ser necesario

Comment: ¿Has refrescado el `JTextArea`?

Comment: @JDev no, no reconozco el código para hacerlo.